# There is any GPSR tracker with the ELM327 features?

Tags: gps, gprs, obd-ii, telemetry

I'm looking for a device who has the capability to be a GPSR tracker and have the same features like ELM327 OBD II has. The features I'm talking about are:

- Engine RPM
- Calculated Load Value
- Coolant Temperature
- Fuel System Status
- Vehicle Speed
- Short Term Fuel Trim
- Long Term Fuel Trim
- Intake Manifold Pressure
- Timing Advance
- Intake Air Temperature
- Air Flow Rate
- Absolute Throttle Position
- Oxygen sensor voltages/associated short term fuel trims
- Fuel System status
- Fuel Pressure
- ...over 4,000 - 15,000 additional values.

I've found some devices but none of them has this features...

Comment: I have tried out those Trackers which plug into the OBD2 readers. The only problem I had, was that the position of the OBD2 port (under the dash), made it harder to get GPS Position info. For me, having that information to track my vehicle was more important. So I found it quite useless.
But if you are using it just to remotely monitor the vehicle obd2 data, then they are fine. Just note, your level of data won't be same as logging it directly.

Comment: @DamienDevillian OBDII extender cable might help your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not mentioned any platforms, I write 3 opportunities you have and you can spread it further!

1) You can use Arduino Uno or Raspberry Pi with Arduino kits.

For instance, combining Raspberry Pi and Arduino geolocation tracker (GPRS + GPS) kit and a CAN Bus Module, you can get what you want. There are many good examples and libraries for C++ and Python. For a rough idea look at [Cooking Hacks website](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/), [Realtime GPS+GPRS Tracking example](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/projects/arduino-realtime-gps-gprs-vehicle-tracking) and [CAN Bus Module Tutorial for Arduino and Raspberry Pi](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/can-bus-module-shield-tutorial-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/).

2) Alternative is using a mobile device (cellphone) using a Bluetooth or WiFi CAN Bus (eg. ELM327) and write an app to save the GPS data through the Built-in GPS module and OBD data via ELM327. Then you can send your data using mobile data.

3) I've seen devices such as [TK228 OBD-II GPS Tracker](http://www.t10.cn/en/products/GPStracker/143.html) But I don't have any idea how useful they are and how they work!

I have tested 1 & 2. There are some bottlenecks using Raspberry Pi but Android + a CAN Bus module worked for me perfectly.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response! The 2) choice for me is impossible because I need both location and telemetrics information come to a server from only one device and with Bluetooth/Wi-Fi it's impossible, so the right choice is to choose a device that I can insert a SIM card. If I can't find any device like this I will definitely try the Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Cheers!

Comment: @JFCM you can vote up or accept the answer if you like! :=)

Answer (score 0):

i have found this device which has elm327 and gsm both functions

```
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/obd-gps-tracker-elm327-obd2-scanner_62198702445.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.95.15d42a92zLl08q
```

May be it will work for you it will drop the data into the system itself by IMEI number of the obd device